# jQuery - How can I toggle a custom checkbox with only one checkbox active at a time?

Tags: jquery

I have created a list of custom checkboxes. At the moment you can only select one checkbox at a time which is great; however I also want to be toggle the currently 'active' checkbox.

Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for over an hour :)

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> OPTION 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> OPTION 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> OPTION 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
// I am using borders to represent a checked/unchecked box for demonstration

.active {
    color: red;
}

// Non-checked box
.fa-square-o {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
}
// Checked-box
.fa-check-square-o {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('li a').bind('click', function() {
    $('li a').not(this).removeClass("active");
    $('li a i').not(this).removeClass("fa-check-square-o").addClass("fa-square-o");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).children("i").toggleClass("fa-square-o fa-check-square-o");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not selecting what you want it to:

```
$('li a i').not(this)
```

It gets all the `<i>` elements, but does not remove the one inside the clicked `<a>` element because `this` is the clicked `<a>` element, not the `<i>` element inside the clicked `<a>` element.

Instead use:

```
$('li a').bind('click', function () {
    $('li a').not(this).removeClass("active").children("i").removeClass("fa-check-square-o").addClass("fa-square-o");
    $(this).toggleClass('active').children("i").toggleClass("fa-square-o fa-check-square-o");
});
```

Also, I hope you aren't using `//` for comments in your CSS, and you just added them in your question.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61amfkda/)